# Merge tabular data into XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

If you have a table containing the following data (shortened example):

| diagram.mxGraphModel.root.object.Attribute:label | diagram.mxGraphModel.root.object.Attribute:Class | diagram.mxGraphModel.root.object.Attribute:Group | diagram.mxGraphModel.root.object.Attribute:Definition | diagram.mxGraphModel.root.object.Attribute:Explanatory_Text | diagram.mxGraphModel.root.object.Attribute:Synonyms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company | COMPANY | Business | pays EMPLOYEES to work in OFFICES | A COMPANY is a registered entity that pays tax and which pays EMPLOYEES. An example of a COMPANY is a legal firm. | employer, business |
| Office | OFFICE | Location | where EMPLOYEES work |  | Bureau, HQ |
| Employee | EMPLOYEE | People | works in an OFFICE for a COMPANY |  | staff, worker |

Then how might one go about merging it into the following XML file (shortened example):

```
<mxfile host="app.diagrams.net" modified="2023-12-15T09:41:51.438Z" agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" etag="Dnc4qvgLhjBTuMqDlZ5A" version="22.1.9" type="device">
  <diagram name="Page-1" id="zjpnGh0cTGfn-Sl_1E2c">
    <mxGraphModel dx="1434" dy="758" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100" math="0" shadow="0">
      <root>
        <mxCell id="0" />
        <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-1" value="Company" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="200" y="190" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-2" value="Office" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="360" y="340" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-3" value="Employee" style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
          <mxGeometry x="590" y="190" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-4" value="" style="endArrow=diamondThin;endFill=0;endSize=24;html=1;rounded=0;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;exitX=0;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=0.5;entryY=1;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-2" target="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-1">
          <mxGeometry width="160" relative="1" as="geometry">
            <mxPoint x="350" y="370" as="sourcePoint" />
            <mxPoint x="260" y="250" as="targetPoint" />
          </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-7" value="has" style="edgeLabel;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;resizable=0;points=[];" vertex="1" connectable="0" parent="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-4">
          <mxGeometry x="0.2867" relative="1" as="geometry">
            <mxPoint as="offset" />
          </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-5" value="" style="endArrow=classic;html=1;rounded=0;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;entryX=1;entryY=0.5;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;exitX=0;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-3" target="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-1">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry">
            <mxPoint x="420" y="220" as="sourcePoint" />
            <mxPoint x="520" y="220" as="targetPoint" />
          </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-6" value="Works for" style="edgeLabel;resizable=0;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;" connectable="0" vertex="1" parent="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-5">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry" />
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-8" value="drives" style="endArrow=classic;html=1;rounded=0;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;exitX=0.442;exitY=1;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;exitPerimeter=0;entryX=1;entryY=0.5;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-3" target="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-2">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry">
            <mxPoint x="590" y="330" as="sourcePoint" />
            <mxPoint x="690" y="330" as="targetPoint" />
          </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
      </root>
    </mxGraphModel>
  </diagram>
</mxfile>
```

So that the resulting XML file looks like this:

```
<mxfile host="app.diagrams.net" modified="2023-12-15T09:52:04.986Z" agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" etag="YjCALbafrjGam96Gn_48" version="22.1.9" type="device">
  <diagram name="Page-1" id="zjpnGh0cTGfn-Sl_1E2c">
    <mxGraphModel dx="1434" dy="758" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100" math="0" shadow="0">
      <root>
        <mxCell id="0" />
        <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />
        <object label="Company" Class="COMPANY" Group="Business" Definition="pays EMPLOYEES to work in OFFICES" Explanatory_Text="A COMPANY is a registered entity that pays tax and which pays EMPLOYEES. An example of a COMPANY is a legal firm." Synonyms="employer, business" id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-1">
          <mxCell style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
            <mxGeometry x="200" y="190" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
          </mxCell>
        </object>
        <object label="Office" Class="OFFICE" Group="Location" Definition="where EMPLOYEES work" Explanatory_Text="" Synonyms="Bureau, HQ" id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-2">
          <mxCell style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
            <mxGeometry x="360" y="340" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
          </mxCell>
        </object>
        <object label="Employee" Class="EMPLOYEE" Group="People" Definition="works in an OFFICE for a COMPANY" Explanatory_Text="" Synonyms="staff, worker" id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-3">
          <mxCell style="rounded=0;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
            <mxGeometry x="590" y="190" width="120" height="60" as="geometry" />
          </mxCell>
        </object>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-4" value="" style="endArrow=diamondThin;endFill=0;endSize=24;html=1;rounded=0;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;exitX=0;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;entryX=0.5;entryY=1;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-2" target="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-1">
          <mxGeometry width="160" relative="1" as="geometry">
            <mxPoint x="350" y="370" as="sourcePoint" />
            <mxPoint x="260" y="250" as="targetPoint" />
          </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-7" value="has" style="edgeLabel;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;resizable=0;points=[];" vertex="1" connectable="0" parent="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-4">
          <mxGeometry x="0.2867" relative="1" as="geometry">
            <mxPoint as="offset" />
          </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-5" value="" style="endArrow=classic;html=1;rounded=0;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;entryX=1;entryY=0.5;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;exitX=0;exitY=0.5;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-3" target="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-1">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry">
            <mxPoint x="420" y="220" as="sourcePoint" />
            <mxPoint x="520" y="220" as="targetPoint" />
          </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-6" value="Works for" style="edgeLabel;resizable=0;html=1;align=center;verticalAlign=middle;" connectable="0" vertex="1" parent="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-5">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry" />
        </mxCell>
        <mxCell id="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-8" value="drives" style="endArrow=classic;html=1;rounded=0;edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;exitX=0.442;exitY=1;exitDx=0;exitDy=0;exitPerimeter=0;entryX=1;entryY=0.5;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-3" target="y1CEVnlje7kXY2eCC5fp-2">
          <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry">
            <mxPoint x="590" y="330" as="sourcePoint" />
            <mxPoint x="690" y="330" as="targetPoint" />
          </mxGeometry>
        </mxCell>
      </root>
    </mxGraphModel>
  </diagram>
</mxfile>
```

Obviously, my real table and XML file are much larger, so cutting and pasting into an XML editor is not a viable option for me. I am not well acquainted with XML, and I'm a bit lost, so help would be appreciated. I'm also a bit surprised I couldn't find a similar existing question of this type.

To give some additional context, this XML data represents a diagram (that in my case is a UML class diagram) and I'm trying to add metadata from the tabular data example above to that diagram's XML. As far as I am aware, there is no xsd schema available for this XML data.

Comment: Please edit your question, and add some details about your environment: (1) what database you are using, (2) what programming languages you are using, (3) anything else relevant to the question.

Comment: Thank you Yitzhak, I have edited the question as you suggest. By the way, I am not using a specific database system or environment (apart from Windows and web browsers).

Comment: You probably need to use XSLT with parameter(s) to transform input XML to a desired XML.

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, do you have any pointers about how to approach this, for someone who doesn't have much of an IT background? Grateful for any advice. Thanks.

Comment: If a database is not used, please remove *database* tag, and add *XSLT* tag.

Comment: I have modified the tags, but got no further responses to the question.

Comment: "Tabular data" is a vague, undefined term. You are showing us a picture, not data. Show us the **code** that contains the data shown in the picture. We should also know which version of XSLT your processor supports (see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153).

Comment: The tabular data shown in the table would be contained in a CSV file. Sorry for not making this clearer. Regarding XSLT, this is completely new to me, and I only added that tag because someone told me to. I don't yet have an XSLT processor. The solution doesn't need to involve XSLT if there is an easier approach.